# MySQL: INTO OUTFILE csv in /home/* folder (Errcode:13)

Tags: mysql, csv, ubuntu, apparmor

I want to export an CSV into /home/test/log/a/logfile.csv.

Actually I am using

```
SELECT activity, timestamp FROM logging WHERE user = 'a' INTO OUTFILE '/home/test/log/a/logfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Now I get

> Can't create/write to file '/home/test/log/a/logfile.csv' (Errcode: 13)

I already tried putting

```
  /home/test/ r,
  /home/test/** rwk,
```

AND

```
  /home/test/log/a/ rwk,
```

into the /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld and give /home/test/log/a rwx for others, but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: the mysql user doesn't have the rights to access the `test` user's directory. just write the file out to `/tmp`, then move it to wherever it has to go.

Comment: I hoped I could avoid this. But then I will write to a different folder and move it afterwards. Thats not very usable because the query above is executed in a loop for multiple users, but alright. :)

Comment: you need to grant access to all directories in the path. granting mysql rights on `a` is useless if mysql can't get into `log` to start with. e.g. it's the equivalent of putting a "free taken one" basket inside a locked bank vault.

Comment: Nice comparison ;-)
But what if I have multiple users with multiple subfolders unter log. In this case I would have to add a lot of paths (automatically) - I think I would prefer the "save in tmp & move"-solution.

Comment: Worked well with the temporary folder.